# Sum taken over the specified set of integer: $\sum_{3 \mid n} a_n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let's consider a sum $$S_{m}=\sum_{ 3 | n}^{m} {a_{n}}$$ where the sum is taken over all the integers $3t$, where $0 \leq 3t \leq m$. Assume that $G(z)$ is a generating function of the sequence $b_{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}{a_{n}}$. How to derive a generating function $$G_{1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{S_{k} z^{k}}$$ with the knowledge of $G(z)$?

For the sum $S_{m}= \sum_{2 | n}^{m}{a_{n}}$ and corresponding $A(z)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{n}^{t}{a_{n}} \cdot z^{t}}$ it can be done: $G(z)=\frac{1}{2}(A(\sqrt{z})+A(-\sqrt{z}))$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a mess. $S_k$ does not depend on $z$, in particular.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Now it should look better. )

Comment: $G(-z)$ is close to the $z$-transform of the $a_n$, with $z=e^{i\omega}$ you get the discrete Fourier transform, for which you get the same convolution/product relations as with the Laplace/Fourier transform. thus, there is some convolution of $G(e^{i\omega})$ involved

Comment: No, $$\frac{A(z)+A(-z)}2=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^{2t} a_n\right)z^{2t},$$ which is very different from the case you are looking for with $3$ above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Yes, you're  right, putting roots makes it better.

Comment: A simple case of discrete Fourier transform: $$G_1(z)=\sum_{n,k}a_{3n}z^k\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant 3n\leqslant k}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_{3n}z^{3n}\frac{1}{1-z}$$ and $$3\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_{3n}z^{3n}=G(z)+G(jz)+G(j^2z)\qquad j=e^{2i\pi/3}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: @Did, you should post that as an answer. But please don't use $j$, some use $j = \sqrt{-1}$, usual for roots of $1$ is $\omega$.

Comment: @vonbrand You might be right about $j$. To me, $\omega$ is not perfect either, being non specific to *cubic* roots of unity. (And you know, to a probabilist, using $\omega$ for anything else than the elements of a sample space...) Thanks for the comment anyway.